# Intersection of subspace and subcubes

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, coding-theory

Consider a $d$-dimensional linear subspace $V\subseteq\mathbb{F}_p^n$, and its intersection with subcubes of form $S_1\times\cdots\times S_n$, where $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ are arbitrary size-$s$ subsets of $\mathbb{F}_p$. I want to bound the size of the intersection
$$M=\max_{S_1,\ldots,S_n}|V\cap S_1\times\cdots\times S_n|$$
An obvious upper bound is $M\leq s^d$, but for some specific $V$ I expect much better bounds.

The parameters I'm interested in are, for instance, $d=n^{1/2}$, $s=2^{\log^2 n}$ and $p=2^{\log^{100} n}$.

1. The specific $V$ I have in mind is Reed-Solomon codes, i.e. each point in $V$ represents the evaluations of a degree-$(d-1)$ polynomial on $\mathbb{F}_p$. In this case, for very small $s$ we have a much better bound on $M$: By counting the tuples $(x,y,i)$ with $x,y\in V$ and $x_i=y_i$, we get that $M\leq s^2$ when $s<n/d$. However this does not work for the parameters listed above. What is the best bound we can get for Reed-Solomon codes?

   - Notice that when $S_1=\cdots=S_n=\mathbb{F}_s$ is a subfield, and the $n$ points being evaluated at are also contained in $\mathbb{F}_s$, we indeed have $M=s^d$. So let us assume that the evaluation points are optimally chosen, or even directly assume $p$ is a prime number to avoid this scenario.
2. More generally, can we get strong bounds like $M\leq 2^{\mathrm{polylog}(n)}$ for any explicitly constructed $V$?
3. Even more generally, what about explicitly constructed **subsets** $V\subseteq\mathbb{F}_p^n$ of size $p^d$? Notice that for a random subset $V$, it is easy to show that $M\leq O(s)$ with high probability.
4. Side question: What about $V$ being a random $d$-dimensional linear (or affine) subspace? This is not as easy as the random subset case, but I still expect $M$ is small with high probability.

---

Let's talk a little bit about the applications as requested. This is related to several problems in theoretical computer science, the most closely related one being static **data structure lower bounds**.

Consider the task of storing the element $x\in V$ (e.g. storing a degree-$(d-1)$ polynomial) in $r$ bits with little or no redundancy, so $r=(1+o(1))\cdot d\log p$. We want that each coordinate $x_i\in\mathbb{F}_p$ can be recovered (e.g. asking for the evaluation of the polynomial) by querying only $q$ stored bits, and our goal is to prove a lower bound on $q$. Ideally we want to show that $q$ should be in the same order as $d$, but for the parameters I listed above, showing any polynomial bound $q=\Omega(n^\epsilon)$ is fine.

The approach is to randomly fix most of the $r$ bits, and leave only $O(r/q\cdot \log s)$ bits free, so that for each $i\in[n]$, there are at most $\log s$ free bits left among the ones queried to decide $x_i$. That means each $x_i$ has at most $s$ possibilities, corresponding to the set $S_i$. We can then bound $q$ using $M$ via
$$2^{r-O(r/q\cdot \log s)}\cdot M\geq p^d$$
which gives
$$q\geq \Omega(d\log p\log s/\log M).$$
If we have a good upper bound on $M$, we have a good lower bound on $q$. The trivial bound $M\leq s^d$ is not good as it only gives $q\geq \Omega(\log p)$ which is also trivial.

When $s$ is small, the bound $M\leq s^2$ is good enough to give a bound close to optimal, and this is essentially done in [Gál & Miltersen](https://www.brics.dk/RS/03/44/BRICS-RS-03-44.pdf). But with larger $s$, the bound could be applied to more general scenarios, such as when each $x_i$ is given $O(\log s)$ bits of hints for free, which is a model that captures the sequential computation of $x$ with $O(\log s)$ bits of memory. This is the reason I wonder if we can still have good bounds on $M$ for larger $s$.

Comment: do you mind giving a motivation/application for these questions? and some indication of how you obtained the results you claim, as in item 1 and 3.

Comment: @Wei Zhan in the case $S_i := \{0, 1\}$ and $d = n - 1$, this is exactly a finite-field Littlewood–Offord problem, and is completely resolved by Griggs https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9304211. can you let me know if this helps?

Comment: @BD107 Thanks. I'm aware of the Littlewood-Offord problem. This problem is different: here we want to find a fixed $V$, and bound the maximum intersection over $S_i$. The bound is also not good for the application I have in mind: see the latest update I added above.